# How to order in bash, a space separated flat file?

Tags: bash

If a have a flat file database in which fields are separated by space like this :

```
Name    Salary_cost function
Luc     50000       Engineer in mechanics
Gerard  35000       Bad in all, good at nothing
Martijn 150000      Director 
Robert  45000       Java Specialist
(...)
```

I would like to order this stuff by Salary_cost.  I can order this using this kind of stuff

```
cat file.txt | sed-e 's/ \+/\t/g' | sort -k 2
```

But this is no good, because

- The first line is not data to be ordered (only sheer hazard put it on the top or the bottom or sometimes, god knows where...).
- If the order of the fields changes or I add some files, then I have to rewrite...
- It is complicated.  I use number to designate the fields names which are string (and not number).
- It is not elegant.
- The data are modified.
- ...

I have thought of something like Recutils.  But I cannot grasp how to use it for this purpose.

I can I sort this file by "Salary_cost" fields, considering other lines as records and the first as data header, using a command line interface (bash,sh, ksh,...)?

There is a lot of interfaces which produce such output, for example: df, transmission-remote, ps, ...  Even coma separated files are close to this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use head, tail combination piped with sort:

```
fld="Salary_cost"

n=$(awk -v q="$fld" 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==q) {print i; exit}}' file)

head -1 file && tail -n +2 file | sort -nk$n
Name    Salary_cost function
Gerard  35000       Bad in all, good at nothing
Robert  45000       Java Specialist
Luc     50000       Engineer in mechanics
Martijn 150000      Director
```

Comment: Yes, but "Salary_cost" is replaced by the unclear "2".